# Upload to YouTube using Zend - via a proxy

Tags: php, zend-framework, proxy, youtube-api

I've been successfully uploading videos to YouTube using some code I found (Zend with YouTube API).
I modified it so that I can upload via a proxy server, but I've hit a brick wall. I've commented which lines I added to implement the proxy support. Here is the code:

```
<?php  
        require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';  
        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');  
        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');  
        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');  
        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');  
        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client_Exception');  //added for proxy support
        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');  //added for proxy support
        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Proxy'); //added for proxy support
        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException');  //added for proxy support

    $config = array(  
        'adapter'    => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Proxy',  
        'proxy_host' => 'MY_PROXY_IP',  
        'proxy_port' => 8080,
        'proxy_user' => 'USER',
        'proxy_pass' => 'PASS'
    );   //added for proxy support

    $proxiedHttpClient = new Zend_Gdata_HttpClient('http://www.google.com/', $config); //added for proxy support
          try   
          {  
              $authenticationURL= 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';  
              $httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(  
               $username = 'YOUTUBE EMAIL ID',  
               $password = 'YOUTUBE PASSWORD',        
               $service = 'youtube',  
               $client = $proxiedHttpClient,    //changed from "$client = null"
               $source = 'mysource',        
               $loginToken = null,  
               $loginCaptcha = null,  
               $authenticationURL);  
          }   
          catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e)   
          {  
               $arry['data']['flag'] = false;  
               $arry['data']['msg'] = 'Username or Password Invalid.';  
               print_r(json_encode($arry));  
               die();  
          }  
              $httpClient->setConfig($config);  //added for proxy support
              $developerKey='DEVELOPER KEY';  
              $applicationId = 'not require';  
              $clientId = 'not require';  
              $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $applicationId, $clientId, $developerKey);  
              $fileName = "FILENAME";    
              $fileType = "video/mp4";   
              $newEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();  
              $filesource = $yt->newMediaFileSource($fileName);  
              $filesource->setContentType('video/mp4');  
              $filesource->setSlug($fileName);   
              $newEntry->setMediaSource($filesource);  
              $newEntry->setVideoTitle("VIDEO TITLE");   
              $newEntry->setVideoDescription("VIDEO DESCRIPTION HERE");   
              $newEntry->setVideoCategory("VIDEO CATEGORY HERE");   
              $newEntry->setVideoTags("VIDEO TAGS");   
              try {  
                    $newEntry = $yt->insertEntry($newEntry, 'http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads', 'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry');  
                    $state = $newEntry->getVideoState();  
                    if ($state)   
                    {  
                         $videourl = $newEntry->getVideoWatchPageUrl();  
                             $arry['data']['flag'] = true;  
                             $arry['data']['url'] = $videourl;  
                             $arry['data']['msg'] = "Video Uploaded Successfully.";  
                    }   
                    else   
                    {  
                         $arry['data']['flag'] = false;  
                         $arry['data']['msg'] = "Not able to retrieve the video status information yet. " ."Please try again later.\n";  
                    }  
              }   
              catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {  
                         $arry['data']['flag'] = false;  
                         $arry['data']['msg'] = $e->getMessage();  
              }  
         echo "<pre>";       
         print_r($arry);  
         ?>
```

When I execute the PHP from the command line, the message it gives back is:

> Trying to write but we are connected to the wrong proxy server

The proxies I've been testing with definitely work - in fact, if I use a broken proxy it just says "Username or Password is invalid." I only get the error message above when using working proxies.

Any guidance or solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found a solution that worked for me. I used the built in cURL Adapter instead of the Proxy adapter.

See my example below...

```
$config = array( 
    'adapter'    => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl',  
    'curloptions' => array(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, CURLOPT_PROXY => "proxy:port", CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD => "username:password")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is using [turned down GData API](http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2015/04/bye-bye-youtube-data-api-v2.html) and deprecated [clientlogin](http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2011/03/clientlogin-fail.html)

Please update to v3 API, [here are PHP examples](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/php) to get you started.